# Error in Gilbert Strang Differential Equations 2.1 Fundamental Solution to 2nd Order Differential Equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In Strang's Differential Equations and Linear Algebra book, Section 2.1, he introduces the fundamental solution / impulse response $g(t)$ to the delta forcing function:

$$m g'' + kg = \delta(t) $$

with given initial conditions $g(0) = 0$ and $g'(0) = 0$. He then says this implies that $g'(0) = 1/m$, since

$$ m g''(0) + k g(0) = \delta(t) \rightarrow m g''(0) = \delta(t) \rightarrow m g'(0) = 1 \rightarrow g'(0) = \frac{1}{m}$$

I'm confused how this doesn't contradict the initial given condition $g'(0) = 0$. Could someone please clarify?

Edit 1: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the text. I don't find Strang easy to follow. Photo below:

[image]

Comment: I'd be curious to see a screenshot of the page where Strang says this.

Comment: I'm never comfortable with the loose way distributions are handled with differential equations.

Comment: I would guess he means $\lim_{t \downarrow 0} g'(t) = {1 \over m}$. Integrate the ode over some small interval containing $0$. This gives $m (g'(\epsilon)-g'(0)) + k \int_0^\epsilon g(s)ds = 1$ and taking limits gives the 'result'.

Comment: @littleO I added a photo. It's quite possible I'm misunderstanding the text.

Comment: On a related note, can any of you suggest an alternative text? I find Strang really hard to follow. I struggled with his linear algebra book before finding another I liked much much more.

Comment: In that picture, I don't see where Strang says that $g'(0) = 0$. Where is it?

Comment: @littleO for a 2nd order ODE, two initial conditions are required: g(0) and g'(0). When he says "with zero initial conditions," I interpret this to to mean g(0)=0 and g'(0)=0.

Comment: @littleO , to specifically answer your question, the text on the right side of Equation 14

Comment: Hmm, I agree that the text in that highlighted box seems confusing. I bet we could guess what he meant to say, though.

Comment: When you see a $\delta$ as input you need to suspend belief a little and think of it as an idealisation (which it is). Think of $g'$ as a piecewise continuous function which has a discontinuity at $t=0$. The effect of the $\delta$ is to 'inject' the ${1 \over m}$ at $t=0$. So view it as a quiescent ode beforehand and one in which $g'(0)$ is suddenly no longer zero moments afterwards. Or view the solution as the limit of the solutions of approximations to a $\delta$ (this of course requires a lot more machinery to establish formally). The effect will be the same as if $g'(0) = {1 \over m}$.

Comment: I have never found a text that addresses these things in a manner I found satisfactory.

Comment: Yes, I agree with this. I had the same confusion, but later I realized that the so-called "ZERO" initial conditions should be written explicitly as $g'(0^-) = 0$. Thus I assume where Strang will still be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that Strang didn't do a great job here... I'm particularly disappointed by his lack of clarification on the domains of his solutions, since this one in particular is implied to be the solution for positive time only. Anyways, on to answering what is happening here (and sorry I'm so late to the game):

For functions with the step function $H(t)$ or the impact function $δ(t)$, there is a strange change in $y$ at $t = 0$ (for $H(t)$, there's a jump from $0$ to $1$, and $δ(t)$ has an instantaneous impact), but besides that point the equation is pretty run-of-the-mill.

For a differential equation $Ay'' + By' + Cy = δ(t)$, it is not inaccurate to say that for $t ≠ 0$, the equation is just the homogeneous version of itself: $Ay'' + By' + Cy = 0$. **However**, the instantaneous impact at $t = 0$ of course has *some* effect on the equation, and it can't just be said that we can replace it with zero. But we are certain with this approach that the solution $y$ of $Ay'' + By' + Cy = δ(t)$ for $t < 0$ is a solution of the homogeneous equation above, and that the solution for $t > 0$ is another solution of the homogeneous equation, but is different than that for the solution of $t < 0$ *because of the impact*. In other words, **the effect of the delta function here is to change the initial conditions of the solution**.

So, Strang is saying that given initial rest conditions $g(0)=g'(0)=0$ for $mg'' + kg = δ(t)$, the solution *specifically* for the domain $t > 0$ is identical to the solution of $mg'' + kg = 0$ with $g(0)=0$ and $g'(0)=\frac{1}{m}$.

Since I'm so late to answering this, I can only hope to help someone else who stumbled across this.

Comment: Yes I did mean that, thanks for catching that. Edited above.